# How to handle popup window in Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm new to selenium, i'm trying to do basic programming for login page, when i enter a wrong password i get pop up box saying invalid password or username with ok button, but selenium RC is not recognizing that pop up window, how do i code that selenium would recognize that. This is the code ive used,

```
public void nlogin()
        {
            selenium.Open("/login.aspx");
            selenium.Type("Login1_UserName", "abcd");
            selenium.Type("Login1_Password", "welcome");
            try
            {
                selenium.Click("Login1_LoginButton");
                Assert.AreEqual("ok", selenium.GetAlert());
                selenium.WaitForPopUp("ok", "3000");
                selenium.Click("ok");

            }
               catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }
```

Please help me with regards to this.

Comment: Please remove the empty catch block and post some of the stack trace. (Empty catch blocks are always wrong).

Answer (score 0):

use `selenium.getAlert()` it will return the string contained in the JavaScript alert.

Answer (score 0):

`WaitForPopUp()` is not for alert boxes it's for new browser windows.
You also do not need the `Click()` to press the ok button on the alert box, the `GetAlert()` does this for you.

Your code should read:

```
public void nlogin()
    {
        selenium.Open("/login.aspx");
        selenium.Type("Login1_UserName", "abcd");
        selenium.Type("Login1_Password", "welcome");
        selenium.Click("Login1_LoginButton");
        Assert.AreEqual("ok", selenium.GetAlert());
    }
```

Also `GetAlert()` gets the content of the alert box, surely this is some kind of warning message rather than the text "ok".

You may want to look through the NDoc documentation for selenium which can be found [here](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/dotnet/)

Comment: The link is dead.